# C# entity datetime returns date but time is always 00:00:00

Tags: c#, sql, datetime, entity-framework-4

When I look in my database, the Date field of the Connections table, wich type is DateTime, has the value 2012-03-01 01:49:02.097.

But when I want to check if the user connected in the last hour :

```
if (user.Connections.Max(t => t.Date).Date.AddHours(1) > DateTime.Now)
```

The time part of the Date is always zero.

So my code only works between midnight and 1 hour in the morning haha!

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two meanings of `.Date` in this, which is making for some confusion; here:

```
t => t.Date
```

this means "access the member called `Date`, a `DateTime`"; so here:

```
.Max(t => t.Date)
```

this means "find the maximum over all `Date` members, a `DateTime`"

However! This:

```
).Date.A
 ^^^^^
```

means "take the date-only part of this value" (any `DateTime` has a `.Date` member which is the date-only part of the value); so yes: that goes to midnight, then you add an hour. So; don't do that! What you want is probably:

```
if (user.Connections.Max(t => t.Date).AddHours(1) > DateTime.Now)
```

or perhaps more efficiently:

```
var cutoff = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1);
if (user.Connections.Any(t => t.Date > cutoff)) {
    ...
}
```

sine that can short-circuit.

Comment: I should use more significant names in my database!